# Solid State Hard Drive Benchmarks

Tags: performance

I've heard a lot about people using Solid State Hard Drives with SharePoint lately. Have you seen a good benchmark published? I'd like to have some hard evidence before I spend a large amount of money on a very new technology like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom:

Chris O'Brien (@ChrisO_Brien) pointed me to this series of articles today in a tweet: "This seems to be the authoritative SSD benchmarking - http://bit.ly/J1FNf"

If this isn't more information than you'll ever need to know, then I don't know what else you could need!

M.

Comment: I've liked AnandTech and Tom's Hardware for these kinds of things in the past. Thanks, Marc.